# CSS - Invalid Property Value (background-image)

Tags: html, css

The "Invalid Property Value" error shows up when I try to set the background-image property in CSS (I'm using laravel, and blade directives).
In the inspector it even shows the proper image to be displayed, but with the error.
Here's the code:

```
@foreach($objects as $object)
<div class="col-5" style="margin: 2%;">
  <button id="game" style="width:100%; background-image: {{asset("img/games/".$object->gameImage)}}; background-size:auto; "> <!-- welp. -->
    <h2><a href="/pagina/{{$object['id']}}" style="text-align:center;"> {{$object['name']}} </a></h2>
  </button>
</div>
@endforeach
```

also, the objects it's referring to is a dynamic array, made so it can be applied to all entries of that type (object's).

Comment: Please add the generated html, the code you pasted is not the actual html the browser sees.

Answer (score 1):

you are using double quote inside the double quote. Please use single quote for inside strings

The corrected code as below:

```
@foreach($objects as $object)
    <div class="col-5" style="margin: 2%;">
      <button id="game" style="width:100%; background-image: url({{asset('img/games/'.$object->gameImage)}}); background-size:auto; "> <!-- welp. -->
        <h2><a href="/pagina/{{$object['id']}}" style="text-align:center;"> {{$object['name']}} </a></h2>
      </button>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Have just tried this, and the issue remains...
Thank you for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `background-color: 'image-path'` to `background-color: url('image-path')`.

```
 @foreach($objects as $object)
    <div class="col-5" style="margin: 2%;">
      <button id="game" style="width:100%; background-image: url({{asset("img/games/".$object->gameImage)}}); background-size:auto; "> <!-- welp. -->
        <h2><a href="/pagina/{{$object['id']}}" style="text-align:center;"> {{$object['name']}} </a></h2>
      </button>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: I have already tried this, and the issue remained.
Thank you anyway!